# Spring - Storing images as byte arrays in database, and retrieving them

Tags: java, android, spring

So im working on an android app, where you can take a picture and it gets saved on the back-end. On the back-end, the entity that holds the picture is this:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Lob
    private byte[] imageBytes;
}
```

From my android app, i get a picture, get its bitmap, compress is to a byte array, and send it to the back-end. When the byte array gets to the server, it looks something like this: `{-1, 30, 50 ...}`, but when it gets saved to the database, it'saved like a string, something like this:

```
"imageBytes": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/....
```

Is it normal for byte arrays to be saved like this? Is @Lob doing this? And the main question:

- When i retrieve this String (which i was expecting to be a byte array), in my android app, how can i transform it to a byte[] array so i can turn it to a bitmap and then in to an image?

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of LOBs: binary LOBs (BLOB) and character LOBs (CLOB).

You may want to use BLOB:

```java
@Lob
@Column(name = "image_bytes", columnDefinition="BLOB")
private byte[] imageBytes;
```

Comment: It still goes in the database as a String.

Answer (score 0):

### Storing an image (byte-array) to a database.

Programing languages and databases have different data types. In order to store data in a database, one has to convert between these data types.

Since there is no SQL native array-like data type, the engine will represent (**encode**) that information in a specific way (in your case, something that looks like a string). This is why, when you query the database yourself, you don't see the array.
For example, the java code representing the byte array may look like this:

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "photo", columnDefinition="BLOB")
private byte[] photo;
```

The @Lob annotation tells hibernate that this byte array should be persisted as a Large OBject to a database-supported large object type, which, in this case, is a binary type (BLOB).
When you save this byte array to a SQLServer database, the byte array will be converted to VARBINARY, and if you query the database it may look something like this:

```
0xFFD8FFE000...
```

Similar to your string, this looks nothing like the byte array that was trying to be saved. This hex representation is a way SQLServer represents binary data (among some other information, see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) )

### Retrieving the image from the database

In order to retrieve the byte-array that was stored in the database, the inverse conversion must happen between the database type to the byte array.
To achieve this, as you can probably see by now, it depends on the database implementation you are using and how the database **decodes** that representation back into your array.

If you are using hibernate, your image retrieval code should be as simple as:

```
byte[] photo = imageRepository.findById("id");
```

This is because hibernate, behind the scenes, will use the specific database implementation to decode the Lob.

If you try to implement this yourself, then your implementation will depend on the database engine you are using, but my recommendation would be not to reinvent the wheel.